# Time Machine partition will not mount on my Mac

Tags: hard-drive, mac, partitioning, time-machine

I have struggled with this problem for a long time and on 3 different MacBooks. I'm currently running Monterey 12.6.

I partition a 5TB drive with APFS and 2 partitions. One for Time Machine (TM) and the other for general use.

Almost every time I plug this USB drive into my MacBook Pro, the TM partition WILL NOT MOUNT. Sometimes (1 out of 20 times) it will mount if I insert the USB cable very slowly (I'm referring to the various USB-C dongles I use with my Macs).

I have identical external drives with no 2nd partition that I use for TM with NO problem.

A physical partition on a drive should just appear to be a single drive to any app on macOS if I'm not mistaken. Any suggestions appreciated!